# Creating a linked hashtag in markdown

Tags: python, django, regex, markdown

I'm currently trying to parse markdown in django/python and linkify hashtags. There are some simple solutions to this:

```
for tag in re.findall(r"(#[\d\w\.]+)", markdown):
   text_tag = tag.replace('#', '')
   markdown = markdown.replace(
       tag,
       f"[{tag}](/blog/?q=%23{text_tag})")
```

This works well enough, but converts everything with a `#` into a link. Eg:
`https://example.com/xyz/#section-on-page` gets linkified. It also gets linkified if it is currently inside of a link itself.

Internal links are also broken as Link get linkified.

Here's a comprehensive case:

```
#hello This is an #example of some text with #hash-tags - http://www.example.com/#not-hashtag but dont want the link

#hello #goodbye #summer

#helloagain

#goodbye

This is #cool, yes it is #radaf! I like this #tool.

[Link](#not-a-hashtag)

[Link](https://example/#also-not)

<a href="#this-neither">Hai</a>
```

Thanks

Comment: "NOTE: Asking for HTML, JSON, etc. regexes tends to be met with negative reactions. If there is a parser for it, use that instead" - regex tag

Comment: I'm currently using the mistune parser. There are currently no parsers that have hashtag linking. I'm writing the linker myself as a template filter.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
def regex_replace(m):
    if m.group(1):
        return fr"[{m.group(1)}](/blog/?q=%23{m.group(2)})"
    return m.group()

regex = r'''<[^>]*>|\[[^][]*]\([^()]*\)|https?://[^\s"'<>]*|(#(\w+(?:\.\w+)*))'''
markdown = re.sub(regex, regex_replace, markdown)
```

See [Python code](https://tio.run/##VVDPb4IwFL7zV7xAFlomkOnNIF532HG3AkvVByVCy0oJLtO/ndVFnGua99J@P/q@dl9GKLmaprrtlDag0Wm5Ph7UKGEDriewaRS8i7oHu7kED0@87RoEVUKvWgSDJwNjbQR4gvciNLzqIQRhTLeO43Eco5si2qs29qQy4ZVnabAbDByUtHJuixEITS2PwN5szckvlc9kCjADV@veet98Y483vQotm0LCQWgsN65n7MihRDsXajd95XUS89R1DljajBWePjR2Dd8jaenasd5Ql9BGlVZDR15uV9el0QxaQqld9v2HX3IS7xpVxdvPzdNydUeW9EJd50E3A9R5/FeNUT/siPZ9P2FFmgfpOWOsyFke5BlhBaF5kNHzb9CtTcqKrHf9xBLPxCPZ@Ey26yyynQaUWpPF/0wLmN@iTqdracj9PE0/).

The `<[^>]*>|\[[^][]*]\([^()]*\)|https?://[^\s"'<>]*|(#(\w+(?:\.\w+)*))` is a regex matching a tag, markdown link, URL or matching a hashtag capturing it as a whole and its part (Group 1) after `#` (Group 2). Once the first group is matched, the replacement is the linkified hashtag, else the string is returned back without modification.